# C# SQLite: Do I need to deploy System.Data.SQLite.xml?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Do I need to deploy System.Data.SQLite.xml with the System.Data.SQLite dlls?

The xml gets included when referencing the dlls copied to the bin folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a release package, no. The XML file contains all of the inline documentation of classes and methods in the assembly and has no value to the end user. While developing your application, it allows Visual Studio to show descriptive comments to the API through IntelliSense.